# Dynamic Fill a Model with List<Object>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm searching since 2h to fill a list inside a Model.

So my model is the following :

```
 public class listePrestationtmp
    {
        public List<prestationtmp> Items { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Sélection")]
        public List<Boolean> select { get; set; }

    }
```

In my Controller, i've to fill a "listePrestationtmp" to send it to the view but with multiple Items coming from multiple table in my database.

So first i search for the id i need (tuteurs_id). Then i create a new listePrestationtmp which is going to be send to my View. After that, i need to fill the listePrestationtmp with the results given by my db depending on the differents tuteurs_id

```
int[] tuteurs_id = bdd.tuteur.Where(t => t.matricule == matricule).Select(t => t.tuteur_id).ToArray();
listePrestationtmp listPrest = new listePrestationtmp();

foreach (int i in tuteurs_id)
{
     listPrest.Items.Add(new prestationtmp());
     List<prestationtmp> tmp = bddtemp.prestationtmp.Where(p => p.tuteur_id == i).ToList();
     listPrest.Items.Add(tmp);

     /*for(int h =0; h < tmp.Items.Count(); h++)*/
     /*foreach (prestationtmp t in tmp) {
             listPrest.Items.Add(tmp);
       }*/
}
```

I'm just not able to fill my listPrestationtmp with the data i need cuz i cant fill with a Add the Items contains in the model.

I've perhaps missed  stupid but i'm stuck since 2h and I think my tries are getting worst ><.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you getting an error. saying your are not able to fill, does not really indicate the problem you are encountering? Clarify the question.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Tutorat.Models.prestationtmp>' to 'Tutorat.Models.prestationtmp' Tutorat 

On the listPrest.Items.Add(tmp);

Comment: That is a compile time error because you are trying to add a list to a method that expects a single object. Check the answers provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No where in the OP is the `Items` property initialized so it is possible that a null reference exception will be thrown when it is accessed at `listPrest.Items.*`

The population of that property can be simplified to below.

```
var tuteurs_ids = bdd.tuteur
    .Where(t => t.matricule == matricule)
    .Select(t => t.tuteur_id)
    .ToList();

var items = bddtemp.prestationtmp
    .Where(p => tuteurs_ids.Contains(p.tuteur_id))
    .ToList();

var listPrest = new listePrestationtmp() {
                    Items = items
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<prestationtmp> tmp = bddtemp.prestationtmp.Where(p => p.tuteur_id == i).ToList();
listPrest.Items.AddRange(tmp);
```